# Can I have the results of Google Form sent to someone else?

Tags: google-forms

I'm making a health info form for my boss, but I want the results to be only viewable by her and not by me. Is there a way to do that? Or would she have to make a copy of my form and then delete me from the lsit of collaborators?

Answer (score 1):

If you will want to edit the form in the future, let her make a copy.

If not, you can change form ownership, It's in Sharing settings.

1. Go File → Add collaborators

   [image]
2. if your boss is not there yet, add her and click "Share & Save"
3. Change her permissions to "ownership":

   [image]